# Must all sentences be true or false?

Tags: logic, paradox, bertrand-russell

Suppose there is a entity with which you can write down a self-contradictory sentence.Does the entity still exist?For example you know Russell's paradox?There is someone who says:"I always lie".So if he is always lying then he is always telling the truth and if he is always telling the truth then he is always lying etc...So is a lie a valid entity? Is there a a category of paradoxical sentences?

Comment: Russell's paradox does rule out a "set of all sets", but the liar paradox doesn't render lying invalid, but does say that the statement "I always lie" is always false (inconsistent). So no person exists who could truthfully utter that statment.

Comment: Yes ok but what is the meaning of lying if it produces logical inconsistencies?And dont answer me "not telling the truth" because that would be the same as saying "x=not(not(x))"

Comment: Please note that the falseness of the sentence "I am always lying" reads "At least one of my statements is true", not "All my statements are true". You are right, that the original sentence is inconsistent when applied to itself. - The solution: Do not utter self-referential statements.

Comment: Lying can be used to generate seemingly inconsistent representations, but so can honesty, or drawing (think of Escher), or music, or wearing a wedding ring when one is unmarried (or not wearing one when one *is* married).

Comment: Hmm I guess you are correct.

Comment: Indeed, that is the correct conclusion.

Comment: Are you asking whether one can sometimes make sense of apparently self-contradictory mathematical entities?

Comment: If someone say's " I always lie" we just conclude that such a statement is false. There is no contradiction. Human's are obviously capable of stating contradictions, so as far as that goes.

Comment: @MichaelCarey it is not false,it is inconsistent.

Comment: @Cerise it's false if we want to be working in a consistent system. We have to assume the speaker believes they are telling the truth ( and so are not lying) but is actually still wrong. Besides, even if we take the stance that it is inconsistent. Then it is still false ( it is just also true at the same time) by definition of inconsistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "In this sort of predicament, always ask yourself: How did we learn
> the meaning of this word ("good", for instance)? From what sort of
> examples? In what language-games? Then it will be easier for you to
> see that the word must have a family of meanings."

> "The confusions which occupy us arise when language is like an engine
> idling, not when it is doing work."

> -Wittgenstein, *in* Philosophical Investigations

Answer (score 0):

Aristotle categorises sentences into many different types such as prayers and propositions. I think only sentences that are propositions must have a truth value.